# Storing an encrypted password to mysql in python

Tags: python

```
import sys
import hashlib
import getpass
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
import MySQLdb, random, os


def SQLAddPass(username, password):
    SQL = 'insert into user values ("%s", "%s")' % (username, password)

    try:
        db = MySQLdb.connect (host='localhost', user='root', db='vedio')
        c = db.cursor()
        c.execute(SQL)
        db.commit()
        c.close()
        db.close()
        raw_input('Record Added - press enter to continue: ')
    except:
        print 'There was a problem adding the record'
        raw_input ('press enter to continue')


def main(argv):


    print '\nUser & Password Storage Program v.01\n'


    username = raw_input('Please Enter a User Name: ')
    password = sha256_crypt.encrypt(getpass.getpass('Please Enter a Password: '))

    try:
        SQLAddPass(username, password)

    except:
        sys.exit('There was a problem saving Record!')

    print '\nPassword safely stored in ' + sys.argv[1] + '\n'      

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

My problem is that the script works but with the following error 
**

> (C:\Users\Elsie\Desktop\example.py:14: Warning: Data truncated for
>   column 'passwo rd' at row 1   c.execute(SQL) Record Added - press
>   enter to continue:

**

Password safely stored in database. What am i doing wrong any ideas or changes to the code are welcome)

Comment: You have funny exception strategy. You are handling one exception two times. Don't.

Answer (score 1):

> Data truncated for column 'passwo rd' at row 1

Mean your table has a password column with a length of for example 10 and you are inserting a record of let's say 20.   The record you inserted will be truncated.  And passwords will be broken.

Increase length of column in the table

Answer (score 0):

Possible that your 'password' field is too short.
You need a varchar(64). What is your length of your password field?

Comment: Julian i had used 15 but have increased as per suggestion and it works like a charm

Comment: @daniel thanks it worked can you please help with code to read and verify the stored password so far i have come up with this pass_try 
    x = 3
    username = raw_input('Please Enter User Name: ') 
    while pass_try < x:
password = sha256_crypt.verify(getpass.getpass("Enter password: ", hash))
        if password != password:
            pass_try += 1print 'Incorrect Password, ' + str(x-pass_try) + ' more attemts left\n'
        else:
            pass_try = x+1
           if pass_try == x and password != password:
        sys.exit('Incorrect Password, terminating... \n')